# Find the first position of a character in string C

Tags: c, string, algorithm, function, char

Find the first position of a character c in string

Here is my code of the function

```
int char_index(int c, char *string) {
    int flag = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int index = 0;

    for(i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if (string[i] == c){
            flag++;
        }
        if (flag == 0){
            index = NOT_IN_STRING;
        } 
        else {
            index = i+1;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

The function is expected to return the position of the character, if the character doesn't exist, the return should be : NOT_IN_STRING

Comment: Did you write that?

Comment: Is there a specific question, or are you looking for a debugging service?

Comment: @Betty By the way what is the value of NOT_IN_STRING? Is it -1?

Comment: How could I modify it to make sure it loop through the string and return the position of the character

Comment: Yes the value of NOT_IN_STRING is -1

Comment: What's wrong with the standard [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) function?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is not written by the author of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `char *strchr(const char *string, int c);` from standard library.

Anyway the function should be done in this way:

```c
int char_index(char c, char *string) {
    for (int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (string[i] == c)
            return i;

    return NOT_IN_STRING;
}
```

Comment: `char const * string` might be an idea to further improve this, though.

Comment: Yes, use `char const * string` to make the function works with constant strings too. Thanks Daniel.

Comment: preferably use either `size_t` for the index

Answer (score 2):

You do not interrupt the loop even when the target character is found in the string. So the length of the string will be returned as an index of the target character.

Also it is better when the function returns an object of type `size_t` instead of `int`.

And the function declaration should look like

```
size_t char_index( const char *s, char c );
```

that is the pointer shall have the qualifier `const` because the string is not changed inside the function.

Take into account that the C standard includes almost a similar function `strchr` that is declared like

```
char * strchr( const char *s, char c );
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NOT_IN_STRING   ( size_t )-1

size_t char_index( const char *s, char c )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( s[i] != '\0' && s[i] != c ) ++i;

    return s[i] != '\0' ? i : NOT_IN_STRING;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "Betty";

    for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%c: %zu\n", s[i], char_index( s, s[i] ) );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
B: 0
e: 1
t: 2
t: 2
y: 4
```

The shown function excludes the terminating zero from searching. If you want to include the terminating zero in searching then just change the return statement of the function the folloing way

```
return s[i] == c ? i : NOT_IN_STRING;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use all those indexes.  It's too difficult to read.

```
/* Find first occurence of a character in a string. */
#include <stdio.h>

#define NOT_IN_STRING -1

int
char_index(int c, const char *string)
{
        const char *start = string;
        while( *string != c && *string ) {
                string++;
        }
        return ( *string == c) ? string - start : NOT_IN_STRING;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        const char *needle = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "";
        const char *haystack = argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "abcdefgh";

        printf("Target string: %s\n", haystack);
        while(*needle) {
                printf("\t%c: %d\n", *needle, char_index((int)*needle, haystack));
                needle += 1;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another option:

```
int instring(int c, const char *str)
{
    int result = NOT_IN_STRING;
    const char savedstr = str;

    while(*str)
    {
        if(*str == c)
        {
            result = str - savedstr;
            break;
        }
        str++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and here the comparison https://godbolt.org/z/uCBRm2

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems in this code.
First the flag, if character is found in the string so `flag++` but what happens when the character shows up in the string more than once? the flag will be 2,3 etc.. that way you will have only the last index in string that character was. To solve that add to for loop `str[i] && !flag`. In addition you are checking if a char is equal to int without any casting (`str[i] == c`) change it by function atoi() or regular, simple, casting.
Good Luck!
James